# (Qt C++) Error after running a big loop (Willing to pay)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, process, freeze

My question is kind of hard to explain quickly. It's difficult to explain out of context. Therefore I am willing to pay someone to help me out over Skype. I'm sure it is just a noob mistake.

Basically, I have a for loop that loops 729 times. When my program is ran, I receive an error when the loop reaches 366 or 367. This is the error:

```
Exception at... ... QTimer::isSingleShot
```

The exception pointer points to one of four places every time it freezes, but it always points to when I use QString::fill.

Here is a snapshot: http://gyazo.com/81397af78abd7be46df1bf28960e6f0d

At first, I thought it was a timeout issue, so I moved the loop into a thread. But I still get the error.

My header file for the thread is this:

http://gyazo.com/09fb1eafe8f42314aa918715b83a72eb

I added
    QThread::msleep(200);
for each time it loops to see if it was a timing issue, however, it will still freeze on loop 366 or 367 at one of 4 locations.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Can you at least post the source for that thread-proc? (I keep clicking on the image scroll bars but nothing is happening =P) And maybe the class-def if this is in such a thing. The number of invokes to isSingleShot in your call-stack seem a bit.. overt, btw.

Comment: Sure! :) I'll do it real quick... Edit, sorry, but what exactly do you want me to post? Would this be the thread.cpp or thread.h? my skype is xtmx.s3rious

Comment: The relevant declarations for the arrays you mentioned, as well as the class/proc that is appearing to hang should be fine.

Comment: Sure! btw, This would go much quicker if we can talk over Skype. That is if you are okay with that?

Comment: I posted the header file for the thread. Again, more than willing to pay for some help :)

Comment: @mc360pro how many Threads do you have running? If you are opening a thread for each element I would suggest that you use a ThreadPool instead. There's really not enough information here and the whole "contact me via Skype" thing is really not what this site is for.

Comment: 2 threads. the main one and then this one.

Comment: I know, it is just very hard for me to explain. I guess I will go all out with another question and explain everything... Boy it's going to be one long page XD. But why is there such an objection to asking for someone to talk about it over skype?

Comment: This site is a question and answer site and if you read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) pages then you might get an idea what this site is for and what it's not for. As for your problem, do you have the Qt sources with your debug build? If so, what exactly does the `fill` method do to throw the exception.

Comment: How do I get the Qt sources for the debug? The fill method simply fills 4 empty QString arrays with 65536 0's every time it loops. When it freezes, it will freeze randomly on only those four arrays. All other arrays are filled normally.

Comment: you can get the sourcecode for the different releases [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/), you can also just download the sources for a specific module (QTBase in your case)

Comment: I am downloading it now. How can these sources help me?

Comment: @mc360pro if the exception is thrown in `fill` then you can see which statement exactly caused the exception.

Comment: btw. why is there so many "isSingleShot" calls in the call-stack. Do you call this thread multiple times before it has finished once?

Comment: No. I call this thread once. The thing is, this was happening before I moved the loop to a thread.

Comment: could you surround the calls to fill with a `try{....fill(...}catch(std::exception &e){std::cout<<e.what();}` because knowing what the exception is might help a lot. Because if it's a `bad_alloc` you probably just ran out of memory.

Comment: I have a feeling I ran out of memory. The strings are huge. Any way around this? I'm not couting anything. I'm making a GUI with Qt. Also, if you're comfortable with it... Skype? :)

Comment: Well I'd first confirm it by seeing if you actually got a `bad_alloc` then you can either re-factor your program to use less memory get more RAM or try to increase the size of your pagefile/swap partition (windows/unix terminology).

Comment: @mc360pro We can use the Stackoverflow chat if you like but I'd really like to keep it on this site

Comment: Im getting an error that cout is not a member of std

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39613/discussion-between-mc360pro-and-petert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the 0xe06d7363 code was the code for an exception from the Windows C-Runtime. When catching it with

```
try{
  ///code including the .fill which allocates memory
}catch(std::exception &e){
  qDebug()<<e.what();
}
```

it turned out to be a `bad_alloc` so he simply ran out of memory.